# On-line list of productive Latin-Greek roots?

Tags: discussion, reference

Inspired by this question [What is the meaning of the suffix 'don'?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/34096/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-suffix-don), I wonder if there is an easy on-line reference that would make this a 'general reference' question.

It could easily be on an ESL site or a high school/jr high vocabulary improver site. These are things that just don't appear in dictionaries. I noticed though that there was 1 close vote because of general reference and I thought that this -should be- general reference but I just don't know of an easy way for people who don't know these things to look for them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would think Wikipedia's [List of Greek and Latin roots in English](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Greek_and_Latin_roots_in_English) would qualify. Of course, the suffix *—don* doesn't appear to be on that list, but the top-voted answer is for *odont* which *is* on the list.

I don't know if that qualifies as general reference: if you didn't know *don* is the same as *odont* and aren't an etymologist I'm not sure you'd guess they were similar/identical.

I *would* however, think it qualifies as general reference based on another answer provided: **any self-respecting dictionary is going to provide the origin of the word**, and at that point the connection between *odont* and *don* would be made clear.

Comment: good point on the 'look up the word; it'll tell you what the pieces mean' = general reference idea.

Answer (score 1):

Though not online, books abound, such as [http://www.amazon.com/The-Greek-Latin-Roots-English/dp/1442233273/ref=dp_ob_title_bk](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1442233273).